# Organize a file with AWK

Tags: awk, dataset, transpose, organization

Well, I have the following file:

```
Progeny Sire    Dam    Sex  PENAS       P35         P41
13254   11908   11421   M   47.275811   1322.828674 1719.183748
13323   11335   11386   M   43.29896    1225.57111  1634.436447
13562   11864   11895   M   47.884191   1228.568357 1615.427502
13338   11335   11970   M   45.780973   1196.32757  1561.900145
```

I need to transpose the PENAS, P35 and P41 the columns. These columns will be the new column: age. Visually, I need that file be this way:

```
Progeny Sire    Dam     Sex AGE     Peso
13254   11908   11421   M   PENAS   47.275811
13254   11908   11421   M   P35     1322.828674
13254   11908   11421   M   P41     1719.183748
13323   11335   11386   M   PENAS   43.29896
13323   11335   11386   M   P35     1225.57111
13323   11335   11386   M   P41     1634.436447
13562   11864   11895   M   PENAS   47.884191
13562   11864   11895   M   P35     1228.568357
13562   11864   11895   M   P41     1615.427502
13338   11335   11970   M   PENAS   45.780973
13338   11335   11970   M   P35     1196.32757
13338   11335   11970   M   P41     1561.900145
```

I tried this command but it did not work:

```
awk 'NR==1{h=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $5 OFS $6 OFS $7; next}
            {a[$2]=(($1 in a)?(a[$1] OFS $NF):(OFS $5 OFS $6 OFS $7 OFS "AGE"));
             if(!($7 in b)) {h=h OFS $7; b[$7]}}
        END{print h; for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' a.txt | column -t > b
```

And I'm stuck at that point, any suggestion please? Thanks.
Note, my original daset has 1400 rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is another `awk`, not dependent on number of columns...

```
$ awk 'NR==1{n=split($0,h); 
             for(i=1;i<=NF-3;i++) printf "%s", $i OFS; 
             printf "%s\n", "AGE" OFS "Peso"; next} 
            {split($0,p); 
             NF--; 
             for(i=1;i<=3;i++) 
               {$(NF-1)=h[NF-2+i]; 
                $NF=p[NF-2+i]; 
                print}}' file | column -t


Progeny  Sire   Dam    Sex  AGE    Peso
13254    11908  11421  M    PENAS  47.275811
13254    11908  11421  M    P35    1322.828674
13254    11908  11421  M    P41    1719.183748
13323    11335  11386  M    PENAS  43.29896
13323    11335  11386  M    P35    1225.57111
13323    11335  11386  M    P41    1634.436447
13562    11864  11895  M    PENAS  47.884191
13562    11864  11895  M    P35    1228.568357
13562    11864  11895  M    P41    1615.427502
13338    11335  11970  M    PENAS  45.780973
13338    11335  11970  M    P35    1196.32757
13338    11335  11970  M    P41    1561.900145
```

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { numPfx=4 }
{ pfx = gensub("((\\S+\\s+){"numPfx"}).*","\\1",1) }
NR==1 {
    split($0,ages)
    print pfx, "AGE", "Peso"
    next
}
{
    for (i=numPfx+1; i<=NF; i++) {
        print pfx, ages[i], $i
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
Progeny  Sire   Dam    Sex  AGE    Peso
13254    11908  11421  M    PENAS  47.275811
13254    11908  11421  M    P35    1322.828674
13254    11908  11421  M    P41    1719.183748
13323    11335  11386  M    PENAS  43.29896
13323    11335  11386  M    P35    1225.57111
13323    11335  11386  M    P41    1634.436447
13562    11864  11895  M    PENAS  47.884191
13562    11864  11895  M    P35    1228.568357
13562    11864  11895  M    P41    1615.427502
13338    11335  11970  M    PENAS  45.780973
13338    11335  11970  M    P35    1196.32757
13338    11335  11970  M    P41    1561.900145
```

With other awks you'd just replace gensub() with a variable plus sub() and replace `\\S` with `[^[:space:]]` and `\\s` with `[[:space:]]`.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

*transpose.awk*

```awk
NR == 1 { 
  NF     -= 2         # Remove last two header columns
  $NF     = "AGE"     # Add AGE column header
  $(NF+1) = "Peso"    # Add Peso column header
  print               # Print header
  next                # Skip to next line
}

{
  for (i=5; i<=7; i++) {
    if(i==5) s = "PENAS"
    if(i==6) s = "P35"
    if(i==7) s = "P41"

    print $1, $2, $3, $4, s, $i
  }
}
```

Run it for example like this:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' -f transpose.awk infile
```

Output:

```
Progeny Sire    Dam     Sex AGE     Peso
13254   11908   11421   M   PENAS   47.275811
13254   11908   11421   M   P35     1322.828674
13254   11908   11421   M   P41     1719.183748
13323   11335   11386   M   PENAS   43.29896
13323   11335   11386   M   P35     1225.57111
13323   11335   11386   M   P41     1634.436447
13562   11864   11895   M   PENAS   47.884191
13562   11864   11895   M   P35     1228.568357
13562   11864   11895   M   P41     1615.427502
13338   11335   11970   M   PENAS   45.780973
13338   11335   11970   M   P35     1196.32757
13338   11335   11970   M   P41     1561.900145
```

#### Warning

Note the warning in the comments from *EdMorton* about messing with `NF`.

Comment: Decrementing NF is undefined behavior per POSIX. Some awks will remove fields from the end of the record, others will do nothing, and others still can do whatever they like (produce error messages, core dump, anything at all) and still be POSIX-compliant. So YMMV with doing that.

Comment: @EdMorton: I didn't know this, thanks.  However, I tested it with GNU awk, mawk, busybox awk and nawk with no issues, so it is reasonably portable

Comment: It'd fail with BSD awk as used on OSX, for example. For the rest, even if it does what you want today in the given context, the next version of that awk could do something different or even the current version could do something different in some other context (e.g. maybe you add $1=$1 and suddenly the original fields reappear, or anything else ....) and it'd still be POSIX compliant so it's a gamble.

Comment: @EdMorton: I have added a note about this. Does OSX not use nawk?

Comment: No, OSX uses BSD awk. Idk what systems use nawk other than it being one of the 3 awks available on Solaris. Despite is poorly-considered name, nawk is very old and pre-POSIX so it doesn't support some POSIX features (e.g. character classes like [[:space:]] and/or RE intervals like {3}) so it's best avoided.

Comment: @EdMorton: I am using the one released by [Kernighan in 2012](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/new/) which does support most of the POSIX features. However, there seem to be  different versions of "nawk"

Comment: Thats not "nawk" it's the even more ridiculously named "The One True AWK". Sigh... I have no idea which platforms, if any, that is provided on.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may also help here.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  for(i=5;i<=NF;i++){
    a[++h]=$i};
  NF-=2;
  $NF="AGE Peso";
  print;
  next}
{
  for(j=5;j<=NF;j++){
    printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,a[++k],$j);
    k=j==NF?k="":k}
}' Input_file | column -t
```